# Wildcards exclude

Tags: ubuntu

I want to install all fonts from Ubuntu official repo. However, just using *apt install font** will meet conflicts. So I need to somehow include all font* but exclude something like **-tail* so package font-test will be installed but font-test-tail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for all font packages and filter as required and then use the resulting list for the install command:

```
# apt install $(apt-cache search font | grep '^font-' | grep -v -- '-tail$' | awk '{print $1}')
```

The above syntax works with bash.

Comment: grep shows "invalid option -- t" but there are no t option... weird. so not working. but I see the logic here.

Comment: Answer edited: since '-tail$' starts with '-', it is interpreted as an option. The solution is to include '--' before the argument (indicating that all that follows is an argument not an option)